# Kafka SSL : Create Topic Error while executing topic command : KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /config/topics/ssl-topic

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka

I have set up SSL for zookeeper and Kafka clients. Zookeeper server and Kafka broker is started successfully. While I have created kafka topic then it gives the error.

**kafka-topics.bat -zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic ssl-topic  --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1**

Error :

> Error while executing topic command : KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for
> /config/topics/ssl-topic [2022-02-06 14:08:24,637] ERROR
> org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode
> = NoAuth for /config/topics/ssl-topic
> at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:120)
> at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
> at kafka.zookeeper.AsyncResponse.maybeThrow(ZooKeeperClient.scala:564)
> at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createRecursive(KafkaZkClient.scala:1644)
> at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createOrSet$1(KafkaZkClient.scala:364)
> at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.setOrCreateEntityConfigs(KafkaZkClient.scala:374)
> at kafka.zk.AdminZkClient.createTopicWithAssignment(AdminZkClient.scala:93)
> at kafka.zk.AdminZkClient.createTopic(AdminZkClient.scala:57)
> at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$ZookeeperTopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:353)
> at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:196)
> at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService.createTopic$(TopicCommand.scala:191)
> at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$ZookeeperTopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:345)
> at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:62)
> at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)  (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)

**Zookeeper.properties** are like

```
dataDir=D:/tmp/zookeeper

admin.enableServer=true admin.serverPort=8080

ssl.client.enable=true secureClientPort=2182 authProvider.x509=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.X509AuthenticationProvider serverCnxnFactory=org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory ssl.trustStore.location=C:/kafka_2.12-2.5.0/ssl/kafka.zookeeper.truststore.jks ssl.trustStore.password=pass ssl.keyStore.location=C:/kafka_2.12-2.5.0/ssl/kafka.zookeeper.keystore.jks ssl.keyStore.password=pass ssl.clientAuth=need
```

**Server.properties** are like

```
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2182 
zookeeper.clientCnxnSocket=org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty
zookeeper.ssl.client.enable=true
zookeeper.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
zookeeper.ssl.truststore.location=C:/kafka_2.12-2.5.0/ssl/kafka.broker.truststore.jks
zookeeper.ssl.truststore.password=Becker77
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.location=C:/kafka_2.12-2.5.0/ssl/kafka.broker.keystore.jks
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.password=Becker77
zookeeper.set.acl=true


ssl.truststore.location=C:/kafka_2.12-2.5.0/ssl/kafka.broker.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=Becker77
ssl.keystore.location=C:/kafka_2.12-2.5.0/ssl/kafka.broker.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=Becker77
ssl.key.password=Becker77
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
```

Comment: You need to generate a client SSL cert. Then provide  SSL properties to the command. Also, Windows doesn't have a /tmp (see Zookeeper data directory)

Comment: I have already created SSL cert that and dataDir path is D:/tmp.
I have followed steps which is mentioned in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hR_OuiqLgOo&lc=Ugw1LHpgqDH17FBsmT94AaABAg.9XzVIF-q8PZ9XzjqESRRfX

Comment: `kafka-topics` takes several more properties for SSL configs, though, is my point. Plus `--zookeeper` flag is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting  `zookeeper.set.acl=false` or configure acl

Comment: zookeeper.set.acl=false is not working same error.